# R haven + ggplot no applicable method for 'rescale' applied to an object of class "c('haven_labelled', 'vctrs_vctr', 'double')" after transformation

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-haven

I am having trouble with haven and ggplot2.

I have converted all the columns to factors or integers as appropriate, but I am still getting the error message that ggplot can't cope with labelled data.

For the purposes of this example, I am interested in the percentage of people with a certain number of cats who do or don't have a specific product. The data is the responses to part of a large survey that was imported from SPSS, hence the data type (and handling NAs in the code). I want to be able to make a percentage stacked bar chart to show the results.

```
library(haven)
library(labelled)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

#Generating some random data for the example. 
number_cats <- labelled(floor(runif(50, 1, 10)))
has_prod <- labelled(rbinom(n=50, size=1, prob=0.45), c(Yes = 1, No = 0))
pets_3 <- tibble(number_cats, has_prod)

pets_3 %>%
  group_by(number_cats, has_prod) %>%
  drop_na() %>% #This is here because the real dataset has NAs
  summarize(count = n())

pets_3 %>%          
mutate(has_prod = haven::as_factor(has_prod, levels = "labels"),
       number_cats = haven::as_factor(number_cats),
       count = as.integer(count))

ggplot(pets_3, aes(x = number_cats, y = count, fill=has_prod )) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity")
#I also get the error if I make count a factor.

Error in UseMethod("rescale") : 
  no applicable method for 'rescale' applied to an object of class "c('haven_labelled', 'vctrs_vctr', 'double')"
```

I can't see why ggplot is still having trouble when I made the data into 'normal' types rather than labelled data. I have successfully used as_factor on other parts of the dataset before to make graphs.

Comment: One issue with your code is that you do not reassign the result of your dplyr pipelines to `pets_3`, i.e. do `pets_3 <- ...` After fixing this your code works fine for me.

Comment: The code you've written here never updated `pets_2`. The `mutate/summarize` functions return a new data.frame which you are not saving anywhere. I cannot replicate your error with the code given. Try copy/pasting into a new R session to make sure your example reproduces the error you are getting.